# How to translate this in Italian?

Tags: translation

The sentence is the following:

"Have you ever sat on a plane before? I hate airplanes. Every time I decide to stay somewhere it's when the plane is landing."

Some frame: a student decides to study abroad in Finland and she talks with her teacher, who's the one saying the sentence, about the travel (it will be by plane).

This is kind of the idea the sentence gives me: the teacher often travels by plane but he hates to, since every time it happens he can't decide where to take seat (?) and exaggerating, maybe trying to be funny, he says that every time he gets to decide where to seat the plane in landing already. The translation should be short enough to fit two lines of 42 characters at most for each.

Specifically the part giving me hard times is this: "Every time I decide to stay somewhere it's when the plane is landing".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I understood something wrong. The original whole sentence is 125 characters long, and the full translation should be just 84?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: The core sentence I'm interested in is "Every time I decide to stay somewhere it's when the plane is landing" which is 68 characters long. The previous part was added to provide further context and I think I can translate it properly.

Comment: It seems like the main issue here is that the English text is unclear.

Comment: Since when are translations on topic, @Charo and the other moderators?

Comment: @DaG: well, since there is a 'translation' tag I guess (big brain time)

Comment: @Bafforasta: Please read [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and under “Translation requests”.

Comment: @DaG: I agree this kind of translation requests is off-topic, but I don't like to close a question when no one has voted to close it. There are even SE communities in which moderators try not to use their binding votes: see, for instance, [this](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3044/19075) (in Spanish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course my translation is perfectible, but I'd go with:

> Hai mai preso posto su un areo prima d'ora? Io odio gli aeroplani. 
>   Ogni volta, quando ho ormai deciso da che parte stare, l'aereo sta già atterrando.

(I translated the whole text.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll take this and adapt it to make a little shorter but it sounds good!